# Append a button to an input with js

Tags: javascript

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

var p1 = document.createElement("p");
var p2 = document.createElement("p");
var p3 = document.createElement("p");

p1.innerHTML = "Half this number: ";
p2.innerHTML = "Percentage of the number: ";
p3.innerHTML = "Area of the circle: ";

var halfNumber = document.createElement("input");
var percentage = document.createElement("input");
var circleArea = document.createElement("input");

halfNumber.innerHTML = "number";
percentage.innerHTML = "number";
circleArea.innerHTML = "number";

var c1 = document.createElement("button");
var c2 = document.createElement("button");
var c3 = document.createElement("button");

c1.value = "Calculate";
c2.value = "Calculate";
c3.value = "Calculate";

p1.appendChild(halfNumber);
p2.appendChild(percentage);
p3.appendChild(circleArea);

halfNumber.appendChild(c1);
percentage.appendChild(c2);
circleArea.appendChild(c3);

body.appendChild(p1);
body.appendChild(p2);
body.appendChild(p3);
```

the buttons c1,2,3 should append to the inputs, but for some reason, it doesn't.
I thought that the problem was the order of the appends but apparently it's not that.

Comment: You're placing the button within the input, as a child, which is invalid HTML

Comment: You should simplify your exemple with only one  "chain" (not three)

Comment: I love you <3
Thank you for your service Captain

Answer (score 0):

`<input>` elements are [void elements](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html-markup-20110113/syntax.html#:%7E:text=A%20void%20element%20is%20an,param%20%2C%20source%20%2C%20track%20%2C%20wbr) - they can't have children. So when you do

```
halfNumber.appendChild(c1);
```

since `halfNumber` (and the other 2) are input elements, nothing gets appended.

You could use `insertAdjacentElement` instead:

```
halfNumber.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', c1);
```

But the buttons still don't have any text, because you're assigning to their `.value`s. Only input-like elements have `.value`s. Assign to their `textContent` instead:

```
c1.textContent = "Calculate";
```

```js
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];

var p1 = document.createElement("p");
var p2 = document.createElement("p");
var p3 = document.createElement("p");

p1.innerHTML = "Half this number: ";
p2.innerHTML = "Percentage of the number: ";
p3.innerHTML = "Area of the circle: ";

var halfNumber = document.createElement("input");
var percentage = document.createElement("input");
var circleArea = document.createElement("input");

halfNumber.innerHTML = "number";
percentage.innerHTML = "number";
circleArea.innerHTML = "number";

var c1 = document.createElement("button");
var c2 = document.createElement("button");
var c3 = document.createElement("button");

c1.textContent = "Calculate";
c2.textContent = "Calculate";
c3.textContent = "Calculate";

p1.appendChild(halfNumber);
p2.appendChild(percentage);
p3.appendChild(circleArea);

halfNumber.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', c1);
percentage.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', c2);
circleArea.insertAdjacentElement('afterend', c3);

body.appendChild(p1);
body.appendChild(p2);
body.appendChild(p3);
```

Other improvements you can make:

- Instead of `document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];` use `document.body`
- Use a function which creates a `<p>`, a label for it, an input, and a button at once, to make things DRY
- Unless you're deliberately setting/retrieving HTML markup, use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML`, to be faster, safer, and more semantically appropriate

```js
var body = document.body;

const makeSection = (labelText) => {
  const p = body.appendChild(document.createElement('p'));
  p.textContent = labelText;
  p.appendChild(document.createElement('input'));
  p.appendChild(document.createElement('button')).textContent = 'Calculate';
};
makeSection("Half this number: ");
makeSection("Percentage of the number: ");
makeSection("Area of the circle: ");
```